# Python keep whitespace in a string

Tags: python, string, printform

How can i keep white space in a string?

I have a string

```
piece = "**\n *\n *"

**
 *
 *
```

and I want print this in the center, but it I use this function, doesn't keep the white space

```
print '\n'.join('{0:^20}'.format(x, 'centered') for x in piece.split('\n'))

**
*
 *
```

I had this output

```
        *          
        *          
        **         
insert a move w
piece before centring 
  *
***

          *         
        ***         
insert a move w
piece before centring 
**
 * 
 *

         **         
         *          
          *
```

as you can see the second move is right but when I print it on the center something is wrong

Comment: Can you wrap the string in quotations so we can see exactly what the string is?

Comment: what is piece set to?

Comment: piece is "**\n *\n *"

Comment: I am getting different output than yours : http://ideone.com/R3lW6l

Comment: For me, it works. The blanks and stars are not printed at the biginning of lines, but in the middle of a 20 chars span on the display - Are you sure you obtain a blank at beginning of the third line before *, and no blank before * on the second line ?

Comment: What does mean _"insert a move w"_ ?? Do you realize that we understand nothing to what you write ?

Comment: move = raw_input("insert a move ") and just change the figure(string) the problem is after piece before centring print something after what I apply the function the print is different

Answer (score 2):

in python 3 i am getting this :

```
>>> print ('\n'.join('{0:^20}'.format(x, 'centered') for x in piece.split('\n'))
)
         **
          *
          *
>>>
```

Comment: what python version you are trying with ?

Comment: same with python 2.7.5 on linux